# How can I add already committed files to .gitignore while keeping it?

Tags: git, gitignore

There is a file already committed.

I want to add the file .gitignore.
I want to keep the file.

for example)

```
$ git ls-files
  foo

$ echo "foo" > .gitignore

$ echo "test" >> foo

$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   foo
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   .gitignore
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

As you can see, foo file status changed to "modified".
I want to be not modified status.
How can I add foo file to .gitignore without deleting it.

---

Already answered is not what I wanted.
What I want is not local setting.
I want method each developers not using 'git update-index --assume-unchanged path/to/file.txt'

Comment: `git add .gitignore`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe of course, I will add .gitignore. but it is not main point of view. thank you!

Answer (score -1):

1. Remove foo from git:

   git rm --cached foo
2. Commit your .gitignore file together with this removal:

   git add .gitignore

   git commit

Comment: That is not what @SunnyAn wanted... what you describe removes it completely, but it should  just not track the changes anymore.